# Adding redcloth/ckeditor to rails_admin admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

i just installed the rails_admin admin gem to my existing rails app. Now i am wondering how do i add redcloth and/or ckeditor to it. When i add ckedtor, it just shows the description area and does not show the title and other fields. Also it does not format after saving. How do i edit the necessary files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't show buttons, it isn't the CKEditor, but the default text area, meaning insert CKEditor failed.

Things to check:

1. Make sure you set it on the fields, like so:

   https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Text
2. Make sure you are using the correct gem version for your Rails (<3, >=3, >=3.2)

   https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor
3. Make sure you ran the generator, e.g.:

   rails g ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=carrierwave

Finally, check your browser console for errors.